# In MVC 3, how do I make the default model binder treat empty strings as "Empty" rather than "NULL"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, poco, model-binding

I'm using Entity Framework Code-First with POCOs for my database interaction. I have a field that is optional called "Title".

When I get the object from the form, the default model binder automagically makes "Title" null instead of empty.

How do I get the model binder to return an empty string instead of null?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why not deal with null in the view model or controller? a simple `var result = foo.title ?? string.Empty;` will do it, no?

Comment: Because that would violate DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself.) I get that model from multiple places and would have to repeat the null string checks in all of them.

Comment: Could you create a partial method (OnTitleChanging) that does the check that Bala R recommended?  This would be done in one place, separate from your edmx file (so it doesn't get overwritten) and should accomplish what you need.

Comment: Set the value of title as string.Empty; in the constructor of your POCO/Model object.

Comment: @Mark, setting the value in the constructor would not help since the default model binder will call the setter of the property afterward. But you could change the behavior of the specific setter (if null is not a possible value) and convert null to String.Empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are requesting non-standard behaviour, so you need non-standard solution. 
Extend default model binder, override its CreateModel method - do what you want for specific cases, and return base.CreateModel for others.

Dont forget to register it as default model binder at application start.

Answer (score 11):

Old question, but in MVC4 you can add this to your POCO property:

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
```

Comment: Cool. Thanks for posting this.